# What does the following mean: "supply has positive elasticity”?

Tags: microeconomics, elasticity

What confuses me in particular is that I always thought of the concept of ‘elasticity’ *with respect to something*. That is, supply of x can be elastic with respect to y.

Am I missing something?

Comment: In context of supply or demand, elasticity generally refers to *price* elasticity. So the statement is actually supposed to be: "price elasticity of supply is positive". So as price increases, quantity supplied increases.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Price elasticity of supply is: $\frac{dQ_s}{dp}\frac{p}{Q_s}$. Because supply slopes upward $\frac{dQ_s}{dp}>0$. $Q_s$ and $p$ are also positive so    $\frac{dQ_s}{dp}\frac{p}{Q_s}>0$.

Comment: May I ask: what is the purpose of the second ratio shown in the first and last sets. I'm referring to the p/q. Isn't elasticity simply dQ/dp?

Comment: @StatsScared no the elasticity is by definition $\frac{dQ_s/Q_s}{dp/p}$ as it is relative change in quantity over relative change in price but that can be rearranged to nicer looking formula: $\frac{dQ_s}{dp}\frac{p}{Q_s}$